# Setting delegates (for protocols) only works in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

Most of the information I found involving implementing protocols and delegates involves a step where you do this;

```
   DestinationViewController *destinationVC = [[destinationViewController alloc] init];
   destinationVC.delegate = self;
```

But after hours of frustration because I couldn't get it to work I finally stumbled across another way to allocate the destinationVC in `prepareForSegue`

```
    DestinationViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    destinationVC.delegate = self;
```

Which actually works. What was I doing wrong? It seemed using the first method my delegate was never set to self.

Comment: if you war making view controller using storyboard then always use segue for while create object of that class. Your scenario I think same thing is happing because you used scoreboard for making class and not override init method of DestinationViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiated from a storyboard, the `initWithCoder:` methid is called, not the `init` method.

```
DestinationViewController *destinationVC = [[destinationViewController alloc] init];
   destinationVC.delegate = self;
```

is how you do when your controller is not from a storyboard: you init it from the code. After that you have to manually handle the transition from your source VC to your destination VC.

```
DestinationViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
destinationVC.delegate = self;
```

is how you do when your controller is defined in a storyboard and is the destination of a segue.
When you perform a segue, the `prepareForSegue:` method of the source view controller is called, in which you should configure your destination like you want: setting properties, delegates, passing data,...

Comment: good one ! comes down to where and how objects are created , with and without storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way you can `pushController` while using `UIStoryboard`.

**Option 1** : taking reference of actually `UIViewController` from `storyboard`.

```
UIViewController *displayTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextViewcontroller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:displayTable animated:YES];
```

**Option 2** : Using `Segue`

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];
```

In your first case you are allocating object and assign delegate. that does't means while performing `pushViewController` operation same reference is passing. so in that case two different reference is created. so you delegate is point out some other reference that doesn't exist.

may this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic tutorial about segues, updated for Xcode 6 and above.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

When you use storyboards, all necessary context provided by UIStoryboardSegue class. it holds destination view controller for you. So, you must access destination controller throw destinationViewController property.

if you want to manually add controller to your navigation stack:

```
{
    // binds your viewController from storyboard with local instance
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER"];
    // set your delegate
    vc.delegate = self;
    // push controller into navigation stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```